# Coupon wrongly detects money in my cart

Tags: magento, shopping-cart, cart, coupon, cart-rules

I have two products from different category in my cart.

---

**Product |  Price |    Category**

---

Bike   |  $1000   |  Two wheeler

Car    |  $2000   |  Four wheeler

---

I have created a coupon code **OFF10 (10% off)** and set only apply to Category Two wheller.

When I apply this coupon in my cart. This should detect **$100** only, but it detects **$300**.

Can anyone helps me how to solve this problem.

**Note:**
*When I try to apply the same coupon code when I have only Car in my cart, it through error that wrong coupon code.*

Comment: May you give the description and rules to your coupon?

Comment: did you check that this two product should not be present under same category for which you have created coupon code ? if not then share details how you have created coupon code ?

Comment: @sagar, I verified both are in diff category